# Converting list of dataframes to list of xts objects turns data into characters - unable to access [in R]

Tags: r, dataframe, xts

Given a vector of tracker names, for example: `datanames = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")`

I use this vector to collect data from a .csv and put it into a list of dataframes, named after the tracker.

```
for (stocks in datanames) 
{
  stockdfs[[stocks]] = mycsv[mycsv$tracker == stocks,]
}
```

This works perfectly fine.

I am now trying to convert this list into a list containing xts objects so I can do some time series analysis on it. I therefore add:

```
      row.names(stockdfs[[stocks]]) = stockdfs[[stocks]]$Date #xts requirement
##BELOW IS WHERE THE PROBLEM LIES##
      stockxts[[stocks]] = as.xts(stockdfs[[stocks]])
      stockinsampxts[[stocks]] = as.xts(stockdfs[[stocks]][0:2000,])
      stockoutsampxts[[stocks]] = as.xts(stockdfs[[stocks]][2000:nrow(stockdfs[[stocks]]),])
      print(stocks)
```

The problem is, when I try to view the xts object inside the list, I get:

```
Error in names[[i]] : subscript out of bounds
```

The weird thing is, I can still access the data from the console, such as print(stockxts[["A"]]).

Help is much appreciated, I am a bit of an R newbie!
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways of creating an xts object, one via creating row.names and the second by using the order.by option in the `as.xts` function.

But you should realise that you are not removing the date column from your data. xts data is a matrix and if a date is included everything in the matrix is a character.

After your rownames statement you can do the following to remove the dates:

```
 stockdfs[[stocks]]$Date <- NULL
```

and then `stockxts[[stocks]] = as.xts(stockdfs[[stocks]])` will have the xts data in numeric form (as long as there are no other character values in the other columns).

You can see the difference in outcome when you remove the date or leave the date in the following example:

```
A <- data.frame(Date = seq(as.Date("2018-02-01"), as.Date("2018-02-05"), by = "day"),
                val1 = seq(1:5))

# everything a character
as.xts(A, order.by = A$Date)
           Date         val1
2018-02-01 "2018-02-01" "1" 
2018-02-02 "2018-02-02" "2" 
2018-02-03 "2018-02-03" "3" 
2018-02-04 "2018-02-04" "4" 
2018-02-05 "2018-02-05" "5" 

# Everything numeric
as.xts(A[, -which(names(A) == "Date")], order.by = A$Date)
           [,1]
2018-02-01    1
2018-02-02    2
2018-02-03    3
2018-02-04    4
2018-02-05    5
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This makes a lot of sense. So remove anything that is not numerical from the dataframe before conversion. This has completely fixed my problem with addition and subtraction of data using the xts object.. Do you have any idea about accessing the xts object inside the list? I keep getting 'Error in names[[i]] : subscript out of bounds', despite if I do something like this 'test = stockxts[["A"]]' being able to access the xts object.

Comment: check `names(test)` after `test = stockxts[["A"]]`. You might have lost the names of your A data.frame in the xts conversion. In which case you will need to add them again.

Comment: It is very weird - if I type View(stockxts[["A"]]) it works, I just can't open it from the GUI without the error. No errors in the names. I guess it isn't the biggest deal, so thanks again!